# In an Azure function is it possible to write to a Service Bus in another subscription?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have been trying to write to an Azure service bus in another subscription. The intention of this is to write a trigger on a Service Bus topic that then sends a filtered subset of the data on the topic on to a customer's service bus Topic.

I have tried to create an output binding to a Service Bus in another subscription as a proof of concept and I am unable to do so.

I have created a custom output binding using the connection string to the target service bus. I have checked "Use function return value" box.

I am getting a status of 503 Service Unavailable when I run my function

Comment: This is certainly possible. It could be that there is an issue with the target Service Bus.

Comment: It is possible. Please add your code and/or check the logs for error details.